# How do I redirect and interact with stderror

Tags: bash, logging, error-handling

As an example not that it would work but say

```
mkdir -p ${ZDIR}${BIND_DIR} 2>&1 | tee -a $ZLOG || exit 1
```

The above isn't going to work as stdout/stderr is already redirected but always get confused here with how and the format of redirection.
Is there a oneliner or if/fi where stdout/stderr can be redirected to a log file whilst if not successful can end with a exit or return 1?

Doesn't have to have the tee to screen can just be straight redirect to file.
I always struggle with the bash format and struggling for an example with redirection and interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir -p "${ZDIR}${BIND_DIR}" 2>"$ZLOG" || exit 1
```

`2>"$ZLOG"`: stderr is redirected to `$ZLOG`.
`|| exit 1`: if the command exits with a non-zero value, exit with `1`.

Comment: Many thanks sure I tried that :) prob had white space maybe but that works fine

Comment: Apols but say `echo "$ALG" > /sys/block/zram$RAM_DEV/comp_algorithm  2>"$ZLOG" || exit 1` wouldn't work would it?

Comment: It just sets a kernel setting for zram same as say swappiness the redirect grabs the echo as above but if incorrect or without permissions you should also get an error

Comment: @StuartNaylor and you want to write that error to $ZLOG? `(echo ... > ...) 2>"$ZLOG" || exit 1`